# EF recursive cte for calculating hierarchy path

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, calculated-columns

I have self-referencing table and I want to add computed column for ancestors path such as :

```
public class PhysicalObject
{
    public PhysicalObject()
    {
        SubPhysicalObjects = new HashSet<PhysicalObject>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Path {get; set;}

    public virtual PhysicalObject Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PhysicalObject> SubPhysicalObjects { get; set; }
}
```

for example path= "1_50_60"

Here (1,50,60) are the Ids of ancestors to help me for searching trees.

How could I achieve that using Entity framework code first?

Comment: Update your question, add the table(s) structure or your entity definition.

Comment: Not clear. Exactly what you ask?

Comment: you can calculate those with a different calculated property, which could then use the same join table.